# Cannot return null for non-nullable field in a GraphQL query

Tags: javascript, express, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

```
const { ApolloServer, gql } = require('apollo-server-express');
const express = require('express');
// dummy data
const books = [
  { id: 1, title: 'book1', author: 'author1' },
  { id: 2, title: 'book2', author: 'author2' },
  { id: 3, title: 'book3', author: 'author3' },
];
const typeDefs = gql`
  type Book {
    id: ID!
    title: String!
    author: String!
  }
  type Query {
    hello: String
    books: [Book!]!
    book(id: ID!): Book
  }
`;
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    hello: () => 'Hello World',
    books: () => books,
    book: (parent,args) => {
      return books.find((book) => book.id === args.id);
    },
  },
};
async function apolloServer(typeDefs, resolvers) {
  try {
    const server = new ApolloServer({ typeDefs, resolvers });
    const app = express();
    await server.start();
    server.applyMiddleware({ app, path: '/api' });
    app.listen(6999, () => console.log('Server is running on 6999'));
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
apolloServer(typeDefs, resolvers);
```

> The result I am getting in GraphQL play Ground while runnig the following Query at localhost 6999 is :- **"message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable field Query.book."**, I am writing the following query :-

```
query($bookId: ID!){
  book(id: $bookId) {
    id
  }
}
```

> passing variable as

```
{
  "bookId": "2"
}
```

Comment: Hello jaromanda, When I am typing the Query in the gql playground running at localhost, I am getting that error

Comment: The error means you're trying to use `xyz.id` while `xyz` is undefined. Wild guess: the id is an integer but you're using "2" (no idea how gql works)

Comment: I am using apollo-server-express": "^3.10.0"

Comment: @JaromandaX : When I am making a query 
```
query Book($bookId: ID!) {
  book(id: $bookId) {
    title
  }
}
``` 
> In the GraphQL playground I am getting this error

Comment: So which error is it; _"Cannot read property 'id' of undefined"_ or _"Cannot return null for non-nullable field"_?

Comment: @Phil : Edited again !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In the code as it seems I was trying to "===" between 'ID' and 'Int' type, Upon changing the book args as book(id: Int) I got my query resolved

```
const typeDefs = gql`
  type Book {
    id: ID!
    title: String!
    author: String!
  }
  type Query {
    hello: String
    books: [Book!]!
    book(id: ID!): Book
  }
`;
```

> I am getting following response

```
{
  "data": {
    "book": {
      "id": "1",
      "title": "book1"
    }
  }
}
```